# Looking for an anime with people in mecha-like human-sized suits

Tags: story-identification, anime

Looking for an anime probably from around 2006-2010. I remember 2 people fighting in some kind of suits. Not like *Gundam*, but like regular-size humans.

I only saw one episode. It had the two main characters, I think they were friends or rivals. The suits changed over the fight and I think by the end they both got to where they only had enough strength left to use one hand.

Comment: Have a look through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if you can remember any more detail.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the final episode of Scryed.

It's a bit sad to know the end without the rest ;)

During the rest of the series kazuma only has his right arm 'in a suit' created by his power, and the other, Ryuho, fight by procuration, his power creating some sort of puppet.

In the last episode they both use their power to 'create' a suit, and fight.

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S-CRY-ed_episodes):

> Kazuma and Ryuho start fighting forcing one another to reveal their stronger Alter powers. Kanami and Mimori find them, but the former tells the latter the two have a strong reason for this fight. As the two fighters draw their final forms they nearly leave the planet. However, the two later return to the Lost Ground where they continue to fight with their bare hands. As one of them appear to claim victory the screen fades to white. In the epilogue, an older Kanami awaits Kazuma's and Ryuho's return.

**The Fight**